# Software that captures and compresses simultaneously

Tags: software-recommendation, software, compression, video-capture

I'm trying to find open-source software that compresses video captured from a webcam automatically. I'm thinking of automatically compressing like in post-production. For example, compressing the file down from, say, what would have been 2.5 GB to 95 MB when it's initially saved.

Is there any software with this feature that's somewhat user-friendly?

Answer (score 3):

Most consumer video recording software I know compresses on capture. Mpeg and others can be configured for lower quality if you want greater compression, but unless you are recording a plain black screen at night in the dark, nothing will give you the level of compression you mention - it just isn't possible.